# Insert relational data with last id into SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a movie database, this database contains several tables with columns and I am trying to insert new movies with relational data. I am trying to figure out how to put a movie into the database, and and set a specific store where the movie is physically located. Think of a movie rental system, where you want to search a specific movie and find what stores have this particular movie in stock.

I want to insert a new movie, and set stock level to a existing store id. I should be able to search this movie later, and be able to read stocklevels at each store ID.

This is one of my sql queries that I have tried so far,

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[movies]
           ([titel], [rating], [genre], [releasedatum],
            [land], [sprak], [DVD_Bluray], [imdb_id])
    VALUES
          ('Resident Evil 2', 4, 'Action', '2016-06-10',
           'USA', 'Engelska', 'DVD', '123456987')

SELECT prodID 
FROM dbo.movies

INSERT INTO dbo.lagerstatus_butiker (butiksid) VALUES (35)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

My table `Movies` contains information about the movie, and the primary key for each movie is `prodID` which is auto incremented, `lagerstatus_butiker` is stocklevel for each store. `Butiksid` is `storeID` and is a primary key in a separate table called 'butiker' (stores in swedish). I have multiple stores, with unique primary key ID's.

How do I insert a new row into `Movies`, and at the same time make it belong to a specific store with a stock level?

My movies table look like this:

```
[titel]
[writer]
[rating]
[genre]
[prodID] <--- Primary key
[releasedatum]
[land]
[sprak]
[DVD_Bluray]
[imdb_id]
[director_id] <--- Foreign key
[butik_id] <--- Foreign key
[lagerstatus]
[actorID] <-- Foreign key
```

My `lagerstatus` (stock level) table looks like this:

```
[butiksid] <-- Foreign key
[prodID] <-- Foreign key
[lagerstatus]
```

And finally, my `butiker` (stores) table looks like this:

```
[butik_namn]
[butiksid] <-- Primary key
[gatuadress]
[postnr]
[postort]
[telnr]
```

Feel free to suggest improvements and changes, I am trying to learn this in SQL Server 2008. This is only for educational purposes.

Thank you! :)

Comment: [butik_id]  in Movies, what is its meaning and why it is not set in the insert?

Comment: Are you okay with using stored procedures?

Comment: @tgolisch Yes, I am ok with using procedures. Do you have any good ones in store?

Comment: @Serg [butik_id] means store_id in English. I attempted to make a direct relation with the 'butiker' table (stores). I may have to rethink, and change this depending on what ideas this community can can come up with. :)

Comment: I mean, `lagerstatus` is m-m `butiker` to `movies` relation. So which of many possible  `butiker`s  `movies. butik_id` is meant to refer to?

Comment: @Serg Think of a rental store where you can rent a movie, this database is suppose to serve many rental stores. And they all have several copies of the same movie. I admit my naming of columns is certainly not optimal, but butik_id in table movies was an attempt to make a direct relation to butiker, instead of using a table-in-between for stocklevel status. That particular foreign key is now removed, and is now only present in lagestatus and butiker tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert a row into a table with an `IDENTITY` column, you can grab that newly created identity value like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[movies]
           ([titel], [rating], [genre], [releasedatum],
            [land], [sprak], [DVD_Bluray], [imdb_id])
    VALUES
          ('Resident Evil 2', 4, 'Action', '2016-06-10',
           'USA', 'Engelska', 'DVD', '123456987')

    DECLARE @NewID INT

    -- get newly created ID
    SELECT @NewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

and now you can use that ID to fill the other table(s):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.lagerstatus_butiker (butiksid) VALUES (@NewID)

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Ah, this looks legitimate. I am going to try this out when I get back to the DB, SCOPE_IDENTITY is the equivalent of MySQL's LAST_INSERT_ID then?

Comment: @ChristerJohansson: since I don't know MySQL, I can't really comment - `SCOPE_IDENTITY` just returns the last **identity** value inserted in this current scope